# Ruby on Rails error uninitialized constant UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

estoy haciendo una asignación de rol en donde uso devise para gestión de usuarios.. para diferenciar los usuarios tengo hecha una función con enum

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  enum role: [:admin, :tarifero, :user]
  ## Iniciador de Rol por default
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?
  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

tengo un controlador aparte el cual es role_asignment en donde hago la búsqueda del usuario y asignarle el rol..

```
class RoleAssignmentController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.all
    @search = params["search"]
    if @search.present?
        @email = @search["email"]
        @user = User.where("email LIKE ?", "%#{@email}%")
    end
  end
  def edit
    @role_assignment = User.find(params[:id])   
  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @role_assignment.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to index_role_assignment_paht, notice: 'El Usuario se edito satisfactoriamente' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
  private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:role)

    end
end
```

mis rutas

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/role_assignment/index', to: "role_assignment#index", as: "role_assignment"
  get "/role_assignment/:id/edit", to: "role_assignment#edit", as: "edit_role_assignment"
  put "/role_assignment/:id", to: "role_assignment#update"
  root to: "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  get 'home/index'  
end
```

soy bastante novato así que disculpen si ven errores o si me paso algo obvio desde ya muchas gracias..

Comment: Se te olvidó poner donde se está generando tu error o bajo qué circunstancias ocurre. De preferencia agrega el stacktrace entero del error a tu pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En algún momento estas haciendo referencia a
`UsersController`

pero no existe, por eso te manda ese error,

en otro caso, puede ser que escribiste el nombre del archivo

`users_controller.rb` como `UsersController`

o el nombre de la clase como

`class users_controller` y debería ser `UsersController`.

Igual **verifica** si escribiste bien el **nombre del controlador** a lo mejor escribiste mal controller.

Saludos!

Comment: SI vi! escribí mal el nombre del controlador! Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirbio amigo! Seria bueno que pudieras votar la respuesta con una flecha arriba, saludos! @MarceloT

Comment: Ups perdon! ahi  vote!